# How to farm key molds?

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I have been killing crimson mobs in the crimson for a while, now, and I still have not had a key mold drop.

Is there an easier way to farm key molds?

I want them so that I can get the vampire knives.

Comment: I need to know the exact same thing. I can't get the Vampire Knives because of it. (360)

Comment: Note that as of 1.3 mobs no longer drop key molds, instead dropping the keys themselves. (not that this changes the drop rate)

Comment: Cutypi I get that but I'm still on console :P

Comment: Its worth mentioning that the console version has its own tag. [tag:terraria-console]. You should ***always*** use the correct tag, for games like this, as the PC runs a completely different version, and may attract different answers.

Comment: Personally I'd suggest a large lava trap ( http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Traps ) with a room you can idle safely in, then it's just a matter of leaving the game running and checking back in occasionally. If you build your safe room and a tunnel directly under the lava trap you can walk through and collect the treasure without any problems.

Comment: @Timelord64 As the drop mechanics for keys / molds are identical between versions, I see no need for the console-specific tag, when the base game tag would reach a wider audience. (This is why I changed the tags in the first place; check the history!)

Comment: So use the base game tag in conjunction with the console tag like you have now so people know what version you're running. As Cutypi noted, there's already a relevant difference between your version and the latest PC version. These tags give it context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, all I can tell you is that Random Numbers are Random.

1 in 2500 is... not a whole lot, I'm afraid. And even after killing 2500 mobs, you're not guaranteed one.

So, if there's no way to get better odds, how can we maximize those odds? Simple -- spawn as many mobs as possible, then kill them. The key here, (ha!) is that it doesn't matter *what* mobs you kill -- Goblin Armies. Celestial Event Mobs. Pirates. Slimes. All are equally valid.

So, things that will help:

- Fighting off Events in the target Biome (Goblin Army, Pirates, Frost/Pumpkin Moons, etc.)
- Water Candles and Battle Potions (More mobs = more dead mobs)
- Blood Moons / Eclipses (Again, more mobs = more dead mobs)

Comment: There are a few other ways to increase the spawn rates. For one make sure there are no caves below you where inaccessible monsters might spawn. Also arranging for certain fast spawning monsters (like blood jellies) to have proper spawning conditions could help. I'm told that summoning the Brain of Cthulu repeatedly can help because all his little helpers count for the drop chance.

Comment: @Nick is correct. The Brain of Cthulu's creepers all have individual chances to drop a crimson key, just like the Eater of Worlds body segments are counted separately for the Corruption key drop.

Comment: Shouldn't farming via Meteor heads be mentioned as well, since it can be done afk with minions?

Comment: @No.7892142 Not possible as of 1.3 (where Meteorheads lack drops once Hard Mode engages). Is 1.3 slated to come to consoles?

Comment: I mentioned it because he said he was on console. I think mentioning that the heads will help now but not in 1.3 might be sensible. And I think it'll find its way to consoles eventually.

Comment: yea I don't have a compooter lol :P

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'm pretty sure 1.3 will be ported eventually. Just takes the port team time.